# What is the exact reason for WebRtc setRemoteDescription: "Failed to set ssl role for the channel"?

Tags: javascript, ssl, webrtc, peer-connection

When I want to establish a WebRtc connection I get the following error (despite having called: `RTCInitializeSSL()`;):

> setRemoteDescription Error 
>   `Domain=org.webrtc.RTCPeerConnection Code=-1
>   "Failed to set remote answer sdp: Failed to push down transport
>   description: Failed to set ssl role for the channel."
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to set remote answer sdp:
>   Failed to push down transport description: Failed to set ssl role for
>   the channel.}

Do you have any idea why?